# Show that the smallest sigma field of the subsets of $A$ containing the sets open in $A$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-sets

> If $A$ be a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$,show that the smallest sigma field of the subsets of $A$ containing the sets open in $A$ is $\{B \in B_{\mathbb{R}}: B \subset A\}$ .

I was taking $C = \{\text{all open sets in }A\}$.

We need to show $\sigma(C)= \{B \in B_{\mathbb{R}}: B \subset A\}$ .

I think we might need the principle of good sets here.

Any leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathcal A$ be the sigma algebra generated by open sets in $A$ and $\mathcal C$ be the class $\{B\in B_{\mathbb R}: B \subset A\}$. We have to show that $\mathcal A=\mathcal C$. First verify that $\mathcal C$ is  a sigma algebra of subsets of $A$. This is straightforward. Next observe that any open set in $A$ is of the form $A \cap U$ where $U$ is open in $\mathbb R$. Celarly. $A\cap U$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb R$ contained in $A$, so it belongs to $\mathcal C$. This proves that $\mathcal A \subset \mathcal C$.

For the reverse inclusion consider $\{E\in B_{\mathbb R}: E \cap A \in \mathcal A\}$. Verify that this is  a sigma algebra containing all open sets in $\mathbb R$. Hence it contains all Borel sets. In partcicular we have proved that any Borel set in $\mathbb R$ already contained in $A$ belongs to $\mathcal A$.

Comment: Yes I could not prove $\mathcal{C}$ to be a sigma field. How can I prove that?

Comment: @LegendKiller If $B_n \in \mathcal C$ for all $n$ then $\cup B_n$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb R$ contained in $A$ so it belongs to$\mathcal C$. If $B \in \mathcal C$  then the complement of $B$ **in** A is $A\setminus B=A\cap B^{c}$ which is a Borel set  in $\mathbb R$ contained in $A$ .Remember to take the complement in $A$, not in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ok I think you have written $\mathcal{C}=${$E \in B_{\mathbb{R}}:E \cap A \in \mathcal{A}$}.How can you write this?

Comment: I did not assume that $\mathcal C$ is equal to this class. I just said consider this class , verify that it is  a sigma algebra containing open sets. Then conclude that it contains all Borel sets. Finally we conclude that if $B$ is  a Borel set in $\mathbb R$ then $B \cap A$ belongs to $\mathcal A$. @LegendKiller